# kdb q - writing stdout to file with linebreaks

Tags: kdb

I am logging the stdout messages using `\1`

```
\1 log.txt
0N!"this is a log message\n";
0N!"another log message";
```

When I open the file in notepad there are no line breaks. Is it possible to use `\1` with line breaks?

Comment: Using notepad might be your problem, try a better text editor (and/or logging using negative 1 as others have suggested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but if you use:

```
system"1 log.txt"
-1"MEssage 1"; 
-1"Message 2";
```

`Message 2` will be written on the next line.

Also, I tried opening the `log.txt` with a different editor (sublime) and the output is on different lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
\1 log.txt 
-1"this is a log message";
-1"another log message";
```

The output is automatically given a new line.